# Closing threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcplistener

I'm writing a tcp server application in c#. I designed a class named TcpCommunication that implements the server. TcpCommunication holds next members:

```
private TcpListener tcpListener;
private TcpClient clientObj;
private Thread listenThread;
```

and a connect() method:

```
public bool Connect()
{
...
listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        listenThread.IsBackground = true;
        listenThread.Start();
...
}
```

ListenForClients methods is implemented as follows:

```
private void ListenForClients()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //blocks until a client connects to the server
                clientObj = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                //create a thread to handle communication with connected client
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receive));
                clientThread.IsBackground = true;
                clientThread.Start();
             }
             ...
        }
    }
```

In some cases (when the user decides) I want to stop listening to new clients and stop servicing existing clients. 
My question is: Do all sub-threads abort when their creator thread (which is not the main thread) aborts?
Do I need to hold a collection of all threads and abort them one by one or does next implementation enough?

```
public bool Disconnect()
    {
        if (listenThread != null)
        {
            listenThread.Abort();
            listenThread.Join();
        }
        tcpListener.Stop();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider to use asyn sockets which itself provide the multi-threading support. Therefor you don't need to manage threads. See this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Threads don't have any relationship, you can kill them in any order. You should hold a list of threads you created, I wouldn't be so brave to just kill all threads in an application, the framework might create some, too. And if I were you, I would abort all of them in a loop, then join all of them in a second loop, to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in blocking mode, the underling server socket blocks the thread, because it is a synchron WIN32 operation.

You do not need a thread for that:

```
public static void StartTcpListener(TcpListener listener)
{
    try
    {
        listener.Server.Blocking = false;
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(
            ar =>
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
            },
            listener);
    }
    catch
    {
        // catch exceptions on close, e.g.
    }
}
```

If you close that socket while listening, it will throw an exception in most cases that are caught because the context is surrounded by a try-catch block in that example.

Answer (score 0):

Do all sub-threads abort when their creator thread (which is not the main thread) aborts?

**No**, they can be running even the owner thread exits. Thread B is created and started in thread A, doesn't mean that thread B is part of thread A.

Do I need to hold a collection of all threads and abort them one by one or does next implementation enough?

From your question I think you need to. (If my understanding is correct) in the server side you have only one thread that `ListenForClients`, where a few `clientThread` will be created, because many clients will connect to your server. But in your `Disconnect` method, only `listenThread` is aborted, which means that it is possible that a lot of `clientThread` are still running.